# Java serialisation of complicated and HUGE data structures

Tags: java, serialization

I have a Model, which needs to be written to disk somehow and read afterwards (making a simple Java 2D game). Now, there's a reference to Player, which has an insaneload of References to Blocks and Entities. In my project there are a HUGE amount of Entities and Blocks, and I really dont want to write a toString()/encode() then fromString()/decode()... The project is overdue anyway and over here its 4:05 AM :p.

So, what does a human in that situation do? Crawl here and ask about what Serialization does, and if it will work right away. I'm in the drama that it must work on the first go, no much space to experimenter, sadly.

The situation below needs to be entirely written to disk. Doable with a single serialize() function :o ?

Now, imagine this fictive classes(in reality I have 5800 lines of java code and a ton of intermixed data, that hurts)(no functions)(off the top of my head):

```
class InventorySlot { Object[] list; Class type; int quantity; }
class Inventory { InventorySlot[] slots; }

class Player { int hp; Inventory inv,palette; double x,y; }

enum Block { air, stone, cobble, dirt, etc; }
class Entity { double x,y,dir,speed,h,w; /*AND CUSTOMS! (derivers)*/ }   
class EntitySpriteAnimationPuf { Particle[] parts; final double friction, dir, dirnoise; Color color; } // final vars!
class World
{
    List<Chunk> chunks; // have an infinite map. each chunk is 64x64 Blocks.
    Entity[65535] entities; // I have a lot of entites, both types and later their instances.
}
class Model // target class to be entirely written down
{
    Player p;
    WindowManager wm; // Yes, i have my own GUI. Yes, it looks wonderful. Yes its got a lot of data... Yes, ouch.
    World w; // got this manually written down.
    Vector<String> terminal; // Dont want this to be serialized...
    boolean guiactive, pause;
    // And a few more...
}
// AND A LOT MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE. MORE.
```

Comment: Do all of your objects conform to the bean pattern? If they did, you could use Jackson to serialize/deserialze to JSON, and it would do this *without* annotation and without nested serialization functions.

Comment: I do not have any external libraries. pure java. No Beans. This is a no-network-connection local desktop application/game without any grpahical acceleration or anything else. this is my first java project, though i'm quite pro in C/C++

Comment: Following the bean pattern would mean all of your data fields (the ones you'd want to serialize, at least) have getters and setters, for some field `foo` you would have `T getFoo()` and `void setFoo(T val)` for some type `T`. Then you'd need *one* external library to do serialization.

Comment: No. Most dont even follow the standard. `int hp; int hp(){return hp;} void hp(int hp){this.hp=hp;}`... :P (/me C programmer)

Comment: I suspect you won't find a solution for free, consider making everything a bean (most IDEs will generate getters and setters for you, Eclipse will for sure), and then using a serialization library capable of serializing beans and nested beans, like, for instance, Jackson.

Comment: It's not clear what the actual question here is: 1) how to serialize this data? 2) what are some options for serializing arbitrary classes? 3) what is the best option for serializing classes that look like this? etc

Comment: "Is that serialisable in any way?" (Can one serialize selfmade LinkedLists or similar weird data structures with pointers?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is what u need to do with to load/save java object (exception handling is ignored)

make sure all the classes implement the Serializable interface

one thing to know is that, if you changed any of the serialized classes, then

most likely your "deserialization" will fail

```
public void load() {
    FileInputStream filein = new FileInputStream("data");
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(filein);
    Model model = (Model) in.readObject();
    in.close();
}

public void save() {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("data"));
    out.writeObject(model);
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: is it enough if i just serialize Model once, write to disk, and forget about all troubles of the entire World and its poor Players and Entities etc ? (**That was my actual simple question**)

Comment: What does "forget about all the troubles of the entire World" mean?

Comment: @imacacke yes, you only serialize the object on the top of your graph hierarchy, then all the objects reachable are also serialized also!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to write your own serialization code, then [kryo](http://code.google.com/p/kryo/) is a better alternative to Java `Serializable`. Especially if performance and serialized size are a consideration (sounds like they are for you).

And yes, all you have to do is register each of your model class with kryo, then just hand it an object graph to serialize.

You can also then add individual serializers for specific classes, if you need to be more efficient than the automatic serializer (which is still far more efficient that Java's).

It's also (somewhat) more resistant to class and JVM version changes; `Serializable` is quite brittle in that regard.